# Removing characters from column value and adding a new letter

Tags: r

I have the following data frame df1. I want to remove "/" from all values in column x2 and add letter v at the end of each value in x2.

```
df1 
x1  x2
1   aa/bb/cc
2   ff/bb/cc
3   uu/bb/cc
```

Resulting df2

```
df2 
x1  x2
1   aabbccv
2   ffbbccv
3   uubbccv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to remove the `/` and `paste0` to add the `v` in each row:

```
df2 <- transform(df1, x2 = paste0(gsub("/", "", x2, fixed = TRUE), "v"))
df2
#  x1      x2
#1  1 aabbccv
#2  2 ffbbccv
#3  3 uubbccv
```